# Bell number vs Factotial

Tags: factorial

We have  $B_n$ is Bell number and $n!$ - factorial.
So, what is greater: $n!$ or $B_n$ ?

How it can be proven?

Comment: Compare the [asymptotics of Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate) with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 3):

Factorials are bigger than Bell numbers, except for the initial cases when there is equality.

A comment from Emeric Deutsch on [OEIS A048742](http://oeis.org/A048742) says that the difference counts

> Number of permutations of $[n]$ which have at least one cycle that has
>   at least one inversion when written with its smallest element in the
>   first position. Example: $a(4)=9$ because we have $(1)(243)$, $(1432)$,
>   $(142)(3)$, $(132)(4)$, $(1342)$, $(1423)$, $(1243)$, $(143)(2)$ and $(1324)$.

Since a count cannot be negative, and there is at least one example when $n \gt 2$, we need not look further.